# WinRT Open Popup Above App Bar Button that invoked it

Tags: popup, position, winrt-xaml, css-position

How do I position a `Popup` control above the `BottomAppBar` `Button` that invoked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position it in reference to the BottomAppBar.

```
popup.VerticalOffset = Window.Current.Bounds.Height - offset;
```

`offset` is the distance from bottom of the screen

same you can do for `HorizontalOffset`, where `HorizontalOffset` will be the position of the button where you want your popup.

Answer (score 1):

Use Callisto's Flyout , its simple and efficient [click here](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto)